# Can anyone help to how to add modify header user-agent to chrome browser using selenium webdriver programmatically

Tags: java, javascript, html, selenium, testng

Can anyone help to how to add modify header  user-agent to chrome browser using selenium webdriver programmatically

`File addonpath = new File("D:\\innpjfdalfhpcoinfnehdnbkglpmogdi_20452.crx");`

```
ChromeOptions chrome = new ChromeOptions();
chrome.addArguments("start-maximized");
chrome.addExtensions(addonpath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your custom user-agent using the addArgument() function to your ChromeOptions object and then continue with the driver creation as you did.

You can check out the code here:
http://blog.wedoqa.com/2014/07/changing-user-agent-with-webdriver/

Comment: IN the above code you are adding only useragent but not adding value.my requirement is how to add user-agent and value to chrome browser